# Pandas graphing bining/overlaying multiple dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a multiple dataframes with approximately 2 week windows of dates and events like below:

```
date, name, event
2020-01-07 19:43:56  johnnyB 82
2020-01-07 19:14:01  johnnyB 181
2020-01-07 19:12:55  johnnyB 11
2020-01-08 19:12:29  johnnyB 10
2020-01-09 17:59:37  johnnyB 12
2020-01-16 16:40:04  johnnyB 10
2020-01-15 15:32:23  johnnyB 9
2020-01-15 15:23:50  johnnyB 7
2020-01-19 15:12:37  johnnyB 8
2020-01-21 12:18:07  johnnyB 1


date, name, event
2020-02-14 19:43:56  matthew 82
2020-02-23 19:14:01  matthew 132
2020-02-22 19:12:55  matthew 173
2020-02-21 19:12:29  matthew 137
2020-02-17 17:59:37  matthew 13
2020-02-28 16:40:04  matthew 173
2020-02-23 15:32:23  matthew 23
2020-02-28 15:23:50  matthew 39
2020-02-26 15:12:37  matthew 9
2020-02-24 12:18:07  matthew 72
```

I know for each individual df I can find first date or starting point of the dataframe like below:

```
start = df.index.min()
```

When plotting single df's I use a timedelta based on days to bar plot the 16 day time period.

How can I bin multiple df's where I can plot, similar to an overlay, based on the day of the 16 day period?

Also, I dont think a bar plot would work well with the overlay style view. What alternate type of graph would better display the overlay of a large grouping of dataframes like this?

Currently I am graphing individual dataframes like below:

```
# Set start point of df + 16 days 
start = df.index.min()
end = start + pd.Timedelta(days=16)
mask = (df.index > start) & (df.index <= end)
df = df.loc[mask]
# resample based on the day with the events column 
daily = df.resample('D', level=0)['events'].count()

# Plotting 
plt.style.use('ggplot')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
ax.bar(daily.index.strftime("%d-%b"), daily)
plt.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried using a line plot?

Comment: Not yet, still having the problem of binning/overlaying the datapoints appropriately